# Restoring to a known state

Tags: couchbase

Couchbase CLI comes with the `cbbackup` and `cbrestore` commands which I had hoped would allow me to take a database in a known state and back it up and then restore it somewhere else where only a newly installed instance exists. Unfortunately it appears that the target database must have all the right buckets setup already and (possibly) that the restore command requires that each bucket name be mentioned explicitly.

This wouldn't pose too much of a problem if I were hand-holding the process but the goal is to start a new environment in a fully automated fashion and I'm wondering if someone has a working method of achieving this goal.

Answer (score 1):

If it where me, I'd use the CLI, REST API or one of the Couchbase SDKs to write something to automate the creation of the target bucket then do the restore.

REST API:
http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-rest-api/#creating-and-editing-buckets

CLI:
http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-cli/#couchbase-cli-commands

Another option you might look into is to use these same kinds of methods to automate set up of uni-directional XDCR from the source to the target cluster.